# Увеличение изображения с использованием многопоточности C#

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Не могу разобраться, как сделать так, чтобы ускорить время выполнения программы при помощи параллельных вычислений на процессоре? Необходимо распараллелить метод ZoomPicture, так как при файлах с разрешением 2К и больше компьютер задумывается на 8 секунд.

Обычный консольный проект. 
Чтобы запустилось на Вашем компьютере необходимо добавить к проекту ссылку на System.Drawing.dll через обозреватель решений.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ImageSize //увеличение разрешения изображения в 2 раза
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); //начало отсчета времени выполнения

            Picture im = new Picture();
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\John\Desktop\img\example1.jpg";
            im.GetPicture(filePath);



             // ***** Необходимо распараллелить выполнение метода по ядрам процессора
                im.ZoomPicture(im, 2); //ссылка на исходное изображение, значение увеличения 2х
            // ***** конец распараллелливания


            sw.Stop(); //конец отсчета времени выполнения
            Console.WriteLine("Complete. Time: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Picture
    {
        private Image pic { get; set; }
        private string Path { get;  set; } //путь к файлу на диске
        private int Height { get; set; } //высота
        private int Width { get; set; } //ширина

        public void GetPicture(string path) //получить изображение с диска
        {
            pic = Image.FromFile(path);
            Path = path;
            Height = pic.Height;
            Width = pic.Width;
        }

        public void ZoomPicture(Picture ob, int zoomVal) //увеличить разрешение в 2 раза
        {
            Bitmap zoomPic = new Bitmap(pic, new Size (pic.Width * zoomVal, pic.Height * zoomVal));
            zoomPic.Save($"{Path}.{zoomPic.Width}x{zoomPic.Height}.jpg"); //сохранить результат с указанием нового разрешения
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуй резать на куски, но вообще сомнительная затея, если метод так не умеет.

Comment: Сохранение увеличенного изображения нужно убрать из подсчета времени.

Comment: На мой взгляд ваш код занимается ухудшением качества изображений, при этом ещё и тормозя :) по сути, включите профилирование в VS, это поможет выявить места на чем тормозит..

Comment: @Qwertiy: NET-овский Bitmap все делает долго, так что не надо равняться на стандартную реализацию

Comment: @Qwertiy Спасибо за ответ. Вы имеете в виду алгоритм увеличения изображения непосредственно? Типа разложить изображение в массив пикселей, пробежаться по нему и этот процесс пробега - цикл уже параллелить, верно?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да, действительно. Это способствует увеличению производительности. Спасибо.

Comment: @NewView Задача не состоит в том, чтобы улучшить качество. Просто интересно было разобраться с применением многопоточности для обработки изображений. Потому и выбрал что-то примитивное, чтобы нагрузка была ощутима по времени :)

Comment: На С/С++ такие участки кода надо писать, тогда будет быстро. Для .NET существует ключь parallel https://habr.com/ru/post/135942/

Comment: Зум картинки выполняется внутри конструктора Bitmap. Это не наш код, поэтому мы не можем его распараллелить (хотя, конечно, мы можем взять [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e1ba6ce9c451889d) и изменить, но это сложно). Нужно либо поискать сторонню библиотеку для работы с изображениями, либо распараллеливать обработку _множества_ картинок: каждую зумить в отдельном потоке.